# Getting Permission Error when trying to write html file

Tags: python-3.x, save, permission-denied, folium

So I'm trying to create a web map, and every time I get to the point of trying to save the map object as a HTML file, I get an error telling me "Permission denied." What could I be doing wrong here?

```
import folium
>>> map = folium.Map(location=[80, -100])
>>> map
<folium.folium.Map object at 0x00B8AF70>
>>> map.save("Map1.html")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\austi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bran
ca\element.py", line 161, in save
    fid = open(outfile, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Map1.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is due to the fact that you have not created your HTML file at the right place (in a place where you have the right to do so). You should better use an absolute path (instead of a relative one) for your HTML file name like that :

```
map.save(r"C:\Users\austi\Map1.html")
```

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it. Thanks a lot! I'm following a coding course and I'm not quite sure how the instructor achieved this without using the read function before the file path like you did there. Also somehow having trouble getting it to save the html file in the folder I made for it, but either way the web map is up and running!